# How to verify if textfield is in right sequence using robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am using a robotframework for testing and i have following fields

```
    Day:
    Month:
    Year
```

and for US it shows like

```
    Month:
    Day:
    Year:
```

How can i verify using robotframework if above fields are showing in correct sequence.

Comment: How do you define "fields"? Are the form fields on a web page?

Comment: yes!it is a form on web page

Comment: Please show the HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using robot framework with java, insert all the text field labels into LinkedhashSets (`LinkedHashSet<String>`). So that, insertion order will be same as you seen on the web page. Compare with the another LinkedHashSet with the labels in the order that you want to check.
 Let me know if you have any queries..